# PyQt4: Select multiple items in QTableWidget simultaneously

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am writing a program in PyQt4 where I would like to select multiple items in a `QTableWidget` simultaneously while holding down the mouse, like using a paintbrush.  I want to be able to drag my cursor across the screen selecting all the items that it passes through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out my own question after a while. What I did what create a function called `select_item` which I call whenever the mouse enters a `QTableWidgetItem`. Here is the connection:

```
self.table.itemEntered.connect(self.select_item)
```

`self.select_item` is a function I use to modify the selected items.